# How can the infinity norm minimization problem be rewritten as a linear program?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, normed-spaces, convex-optimization, linear-programming

I have been trying to solve the infinity norm minimization problem and after quite a bit of reading I have found out that infinity norm minimization problem can be re-written as linear optimization problem. I have been trying to understand how and why it is done so, but failing miserably. Could anyone please explain me about this and also tell how the cost function looks like?

My optimization problem looks like following: (I have to solve for $x$ when $A$ and $b$ are given.)

$$\mbox{minimize}  \quad \|A x - b\|_{\infty}$$

which can be rewritten as follows

\begin{split}\begin{array}{lccl}
 \mbox{minimize}    & t             &       &\\
 \mbox{subject to}  & Ax + t \mathbb 1 - b  & \geq  & 0,\\
                    & A x - t \mathbb 1  - b  & \leq  & 0,
 \end{array}\end{split}

where $\mathbb 1$ is a vector of ones.

Comment: For brevity let's define $y=Ax-b$. We have $\|y\|_\infty = \max_i|y_i| = \max(\max_iy_i,\max_i-y_i) = \arg\min_{\substack{t\ge y_i\\t\ge-y_i}}t$.

Answer (score 15):

To complement Erwin Kalvelagen's answer, we have the following optimization problem in $\mathrm x \in \mathbb R^n$

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & \|\mathrm A \mathrm x - \mathrm b\|_\infty\end{array}$$

where $\mathrm A \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}$ and $\mathrm b \in \mathbb R^m$ are given. Let $\mathrm a_i^\top \in \mathbb R^n$ denote the $i$-th row of $\rm A$.

Introducing decision variable $t \in \mathbb R$ and rewriting in epigraph form, we then obtain the following constrained optimization problem in $\mathrm x \in \mathbb R^n$ and $t \in \mathbb R$

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & t\\ \text{subject to} & \|\mathrm A \mathrm x - \mathrm b\|_\infty \leq t\end{array}$$

which can be rewritten as follows

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & t\\ \text{subject to} & \displaystyle\max_{1 \leq i \leq m} | \mathrm a_i^\top \mathrm x - b_i | \leq t\end{array}$$

which can be rewritten as follows

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & t\\ \text{subject to} & | \mathrm a_1^\top \mathrm x - b_1 | \leq t\\ & | \mathrm a_2^\top \mathrm x - b_2 | \leq t\\ & \qquad \vdots\\ & |\mathrm a_m^\top \mathrm x - b_m | \leq t\end{array}$$

which can be rewritten as follows

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & t\\ \text{subject to} & -t \leq \mathrm a_1^\top \mathrm x - b_1 \leq t\\ & -t \leq \mathrm a_2^\top \mathrm x - b_2 \leq t\\ & \qquad\quad \vdots\\ & -t \leq \mathrm a_m^\top \mathrm x - b_m \leq t\end{array}$$

which can be rewritten as follows

$$\begin{array}{ll} \text{minimize} & t\\ \text{subject to} & -t 1_m \leq \mathrm A \mathrm x - \mathrm b \leq t 1_m\end{array}$$

where the optimal $\rm x$ and the optimal $t$ are the *minimizer* and the *minimum* of the original problem, respectively.

Comment: How do I start solving this problem? What should be my first step if I want to solve it without using existing LP solver softwares? I want to do it for the sake of understanding. Also I used cvx software whose computational time is rather high. Any suggestion which software should I use for this particular problem?

Comment: You can run the simplex algorithm using pen & paper (rather than silicon).

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more please?

Comment: Algorithms can be run on pen & paper, if you have the patience. Try $m=3$ and $n=2$.

Comment: found the following matlab code that minimizes the infinity norm. Can you please help me understand what is going on here? Why are $f$, $Ane$ and $bne$ like that?

    `A = randn(m,n);
    b = randn(m,1);
    
    % infinity norm
    f    = [ zeros(n,1);  1          ];
    Ane  = [ +A,          -ones(m,1) ; ...
                 -A,          -ones(m,1) ];
    bne  = [ +b;          -b         ];
    xt   = linprog(f,Ane,bne);
    x_lp = xt(1:n,:);`

Comment: The inequality $$\mathrm A \mathrm x - t 1_m \leq \mathrm b$$ can be rewritten in the form $$\begin{bmatrix} \mathrm A & -1_m\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm x\\ t\end{bmatrix} \leq \mathrm b$$ The other inequality can be written in a similar form.

Comment: And how is `f = [ zeros(n,1); 1 ]`?

Comment: That one is easy: $$t = \begin{bmatrix} 0_n\\ 1\end{bmatrix}^\top \begin{bmatrix} \mathrm x\\ t\end{bmatrix}$$

Answer (score 4):

If we want to minimize $|x|$ (for a scalar $x$) we can linearize this as:

$$\begin{align} \min\>& t\\& -t \le x \le t\end{align}$$

This means that if we want to minimize $||Ax-b||_{\infty}$ we can write:

$$\begin{align} \min\>& t\\& -t \le (Ax-b)_i \le t&&\forall i\end{align}$$

You need to split this into two different inequalities:

$$\begin{align} \min\>& t\\& -t \le (Ax-b)_i &&\forall i\\ &(Ax-b)_i \le t&&\forall i\end{align}$$

There are some other LP formulations shown [here](http://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2017/11/lp-and-chebyshev-regression.html).

Comment: Thanks Erwin. I am new to solving an optimization problem. So could you please tell me how do I formulate my cost function from the above information?

Comment: The cost function $f(x,t)$ is just $f(x,t) = t$ which is linear. Note that both $x$ and $t$ are decision variables, where $t$ is a scalar variable. The cost coefficients are 1 for $t$ and zero for the original $x$ variables. So your cost vector $c$ will be very sparse: one element with value 1 and the rest zero.

Comment: So how do I define the Lagrangian in this case?

Comment: Why do you need a Lagrangian for an LP problem? Does not make sense to me.

Comment: I am clueless in how to start then. Could you please help?

Comment: Just download and install an LP solver, feed it the model and solve it.

Comment: But how do I start if I have to solve it myself? I want to do it for the sake of understanding.

Comment: Then you need to implement an LP solver. Good LP solvers are serious pieces of software, but for small models you can get away with some textbook implementation. You need to decide whether to implement a Simplex method or an interior point method. You may want to read a book first, e.g. [Vanderbei](https://www.amazon.com/Linear-Programming-Foundations-Extensions-International/dp/1461476291). In my opinion in most cases it is much better to use existing software.

Comment: Got it. Thanks Erwin!

Comment: @ChristinaLemuix it cannot be solved by hand. It must be solved numerically.

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Any which software should I use for this particular problem? I used cvx but i think it computes rather slowly.

Comment: There are really fast LP solvers such as Cplex, Gurobi and Mosek.

Comment: Define "fast". As the developer of CVX I make no apologies for its speed or lack thereof---it's designed to make models easy to build. That said, once the model is built, the speed is determined by the underlying solvers. And CVX talks to Gurobi and MOSEK. I don't know which solver you ended up using, but if it was one of those, you're not going to see significant speedups by setting aside CVX and calling them directly. And indeed, this is _necessarily_ going to be slower than the equivalent-sized least squares problem---I'd say 50x slower.