# Known results about minimizing $\ell_\infty$ norm

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, linear-programming

I am wondering about known algorithms for the following optimization problem, particularly in the case where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times n}$ has $n \gg d$ (so the associated linear system is underdetermined):

$$\begin{aligned}
&\min&& \lVert x \rVert_{\infty} \\ 
&\operatorname{s.t. } && A x=b \\ 
&&& x \geq 0,
\end{aligned}$$

I know a more general version of this problem is discussed in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.07425), but I am interested in more whether specialized results are known for the $\ell_\infty$ case. I am mainly interested in an exact algorithm (or polylog dependence on error terms).

Comment: This can be converted to and solved as a Linear Programming problems.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2589887/339790)

Comment: I know this can be done by linear programming, but I'm mainly interested in whether there are any specialized algorithms that are more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the problem via linear programming by introducing a variable $z$ and constraints $-z \le x_i\le z$ and minimizing $z$.