# Epigraph form for conversion of l1 norm minimisation to linear program?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, normed-spaces, convex-optimization, linear-programming

This answer contains an amazing explanation of how the epigraph form can be used to cast the $l_\infty$ norm minimisation problem as a linear program: [How can the infinity norm minimization problem be rewritten as a linear program?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2589887/how-can-the-infinity-norm-minimization-problem-be-rewritten-as-a-linear-program)

However, I am unsure how the epigraph form can be applied to the $l_1$ norm minimisation problem. My understanding of the epigraph form is that we can say $\text { minimise (over } x \text { ) } f_0(x)$ is equivalent to $\text{minimise (over } x, t \text { ) } t \text { subject to } f_0(x)-t \leq 0 \text {. }$

If I do this to the $l_1$ norm minimisation problem, then I get that the epigraph form is:
$$\min_{(x,t)} t \quad s.t. \sum_i |a_i^Tx - b_i| \leq t\,.$$
I don't understand how/why $t_i$s are introduced into the final LP form (pictured below)?

[image]

I would very much appreciate a derivation like in the link provided earlier.

Comment: The constraint $\sum_i | a_i^T x - b_i | \leq t$ is not a linear constraint, so it can't be included in a linear programming problem. So, if our goal is to formulate a linear programming problem, we must do something else. Introducing variables $t_i$ which are constrained to satisfy $-t_i \leq a_i^T x - b_i \leq t_i$ and then minimizing $\sum_i t_i$ is something we can do. And you can see that this problem reformulation is in fact equivalent to the original problem.

Comment: @littleO Ahh okay I was overlooking the linearity of the constraint(s). One doubt still  - I can't quite seem to convince myself that, as you say, the problem reformulation $$
\min _{x, t_i}  \sum_{i=1}^m t_i \quad  -t_i \leq a_i^T x-b_i \leq t_i \quad i=1, \ldots, m
$$ is equivalent to $$\min_{(x,t)} t \quad s.t. \sum_i |a_i^Tx - b_i| \leq t$$. Could you possibly elaborate further on this and how they're saying the same things?

Comment: I would try to see directly that minimizing $\sum_i t_i$ subject to $-t_i \leq a_i^T x - b_i \leq t_i$ for all $i$ is equivalent to minimizing $\sum_i | a_i^T x - b_i|$. Note that in the reformulated problem if $x$ is optimal then an optimal $t_i$ will be equal to $|a_i^T x - b_i|$, because we want $t_i$ to be as small as possible while satisfying the constraints.

Comment: $a\geq |b|$ is equivalent to "$a\geq b$ and $a\geq -b$". This is just the definition of absolute value. And that's what you are using here.

Comment: Thank you for this @littleO and Michal. I understand now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an answer, but too long for a comment.

To see why the problems are equivalent:

Let $P_1$ be $\min_{x,(t_1,t_2,...)}  \{ \sum_i t_i \mid |a_i^Tx -b_i| \le t_i \}$ and $P_2$ be $\min_{x,t}  \{ t \mid \sum_i|a_i^Tx -b_i| \le t \}$.

Suppose $(x,(t_1,t_2,...))$ is feasible for $P_1$, then $(x,\sum_i t_i)$ is feasible for $P_2$ and $t = \sum_i t_i$. Hence the value of $P_2$ must be $\le$ the value of $P_1$.

Similarly, if $(x,t)$ is feasible for $P_2$, then $(x, (|a_1^Tx -b_1|, |a_2^Tx-b_2|,...))$ is feasible for $P_1$ and $\sum_i |a_i^Tx -b_i| \le t$. Hence the value of $P_1$ must be $\le $ the value of $P_2$.

Comment: Thank you for going more into detail, this is very helpful. Just one clarification, in the penultimate paragraph, I don't quite see where the less than or equal to comes from. Why not just equal to (if the objective functions are the same)?

Comment: Well, as long as it is $\le$ we get the equivalence (since we already have the other direction). However, given a feasible $(x,t)$ for $P_2$, we need to find suitable $t_i$ for $P_1$ and $t_k = |a_i^T x-b_i|$ will work, but all we know is that $\sum_i t_i \le t$. You could adjust one of the $t_i$ so that we have equality, but since all we are interested in here is a proof, there is no need.

Comment: I think you might be talking about the last paragraph of your answer, but my question was about the one before that, beginning "Suppose $(x, (t_1, t_2, \ldots))$ is feasible...

Comment: I see; in that case the costs are equal, but that just means that the $\inf$ of $P_2$ is $\le $ the $\inf$ of $P_1$. The point being that I am just looking for two separate $\le$s in order to conclude that they are equivalent.

Comment: Ah okay got you. Thanks!