# Reduction from a Chebyshev\minimax approximation to linear programming to find solution vector

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, approximation

For this question $i\in\{1,2,\dots k\} $

Given samples $$ x_{i}\in\mathbb{R}^{8},y_{i}\in\mathbb{R} $$
Assume a linear model such that $y_{i}=a^{T}x_{i}-b+\varepsilon_{i} $  where $\varepsilon_i$ is some random gaussian noise.
Assume a minimum error criterion $$p^{*}=\min_{a\in\mathbb{R}^{8},b\in\mathbb{R}}\max_{i\in\left\{ 1,2,\dots k\right\} }\left|y_{i}-\left(a^{T}x_{i}-b\right)\right| $$

This leads me to $$ r_{9\times1}=\left[\begin{array}{c}
\boldsymbol{a}\\
\hline b
\end{array}\right],\tilde{x_{i_{9\times1}}}=\left[\begin{array}{c}
x_{i}\\
\hline -1
\end{array}\right] $$
$$ r^{T}x_{i}'=a^{T}x_{i}-b\Rightarrow y_{i}-r^{T}x_{i}'=y_{i}-a^{T}x_{i}-b $$
$$ \min_{r\in\mathbb{R}^{9}}\max_{i\in\left\{ 1,2,\dots k\right\} }\left|r^{T}x_{i}-y_{i}\right|$$
Using linprog, how do i find $p^*$ and $a,b$ ?
I tried using the common reduction in here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2591600/841573
$$ \min t $$
$$ s.t:-t\le r^{T}x_{i}^{'}-y_{i}\le t\iff\begin{cases}
r^{T}x_{i}'-y_{i}\le t\\
-\left(r^{T}x_{i}'-y_{i}\right)\le t
\end{cases}$$
How can I now find $r^T$ and $t$ where $t$ should be the minimal error and $r^T$ should be an estimation of $a,b$?
For numpy\matlab I need to form it as a linear program but the input parameters are constant , how can i expect $t$ as a solution while i give it $t$ as a parameter?

Comment: *while i give it t
 as a parameter*: $t$ is not a parameter, but a decision variable. See https://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2017/11/lp-and-chebyshev-regression.html for some formulations.

Comment: thank you very much, really helped me out once i understood why it works and how to build the right equations